# Can I use SQL on the output of a Merge Join?

Tags: ssis

I'm using SSIS to fetch data from two Informix servers. I'm using a Merge Join object to combine the data together. Now, I need to summarize the data for reporting.

I worked up the T-SQL for pivoting, counting and summing the data I want, but I don't know how to do that in SSIS. I just want to run a query against the output of the Merge Join. How do I do that?

The pivot object looks too simplex for the job.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd suggest that you insert the product of the merge join to a staging table and finish off the dataflow that way. Then start a new data flow with your t-sql code (referencing the staging table) as the source  and then run it directly into the destination.

Comment: That's what I was going to do, but a co-worker suggested I can do the query in an Execute SQL Task that receives the output of the Data Flow Task. I have the objects linked together, but I don't know how to reference the input data. Select all from what??

Answer (score 0):

I would try sending the results of your data flow task to a object-typed variable. I believe you can manipulate the data directly in memory rather than dumping it to disk.

http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Integration+Services+(SSIS)/64014/